# Pandas.melt function: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pd.melt function to convert a DF in this format:

df = [image]

Into this format:

new_df = [image]

Using this code: 
`new_df = pd.melt(df,id_vars=['orders'],var_name="samples", value_name="Count")`

But I keep getting this error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. Anyone have any idea what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using your code and it works without any error:

```
import numpy as np

# sample df
o1 = [f'order {x}' for x in range(1, 6)]
d = {f'sample {x}': np.random.random(5) for x in range(1, 6)}
df = pd.DataFrame({'orders': o1, ** d})

pd.melt(df,id_vars=['orders'], var_name="sample", value_name="Count")

     orders    sample     Count
0   order 1  sample 1  0.350265
1   order 2  sample 1  0.697328
2   order 3  sample 1  0.263138
3   order 4  sample 1  0.976091
4   order 5  sample 1  0.370498
5   order 1  sample 2  0.108410
6   order 2  sample 2  0.785301
7   order 3  sample 2  0.497472
8   order 4  sample 2  0.978428
9   order 5  sample 2  0.995097
10  order 1  sample 3  0.366750
11  order 2  sample 3  0.628643
12  order 3  sample 3  0.420587
13  order 4  sample 3  0.490384
14  order 5  sample 3  0.812225
15  order 1  sample 4  0.414280
```

Comment: Actually I shared sample, as my actual code I cannot share completely. Will there be any problem if there is no data in Count ie. blank? I am trying to understand why I am getting that error.

Comment: you want to keep the Count column blank ? Without the data it's difficult to anticipate, but looks like the data type of your columns are causing issue. Make sure your data is in same format as I gave in the example.

Comment: If I update some of the count values as blank string "", is it possible that would cause an issue?

Comment: yes, might be an issue.

Comment: I changed from blanks using new_df.fillna(0, inplace=True) but still same error. The remaining data is in above format.

Comment: try this way: `df.set_index('orders').stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'sample', 0:'count'})`

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Issue fixed, you were right the problem was the data type - not blanks.